# FormGroup Angular

Tags: angular2

```js
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6)
    ])
  });
```

```html
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors" class='invalid-feedback'>
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
        Email не может быть пустым. Введите корректный email.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors.email">
        Введите корректный email.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Почему высвечивается всегда:

**"Email не может быть пустым. Введите корректный email.
Введите корректный email."**

хотя должно высветиться: **"Email не может быть пустым. Введите корректный email."**

а когда появится хотя бы 1 символ: **"Введите корректный email."**

Если пишу Validators.pattern который определяет email, то все работает как надо, а когда использую Validators.email работает неправильно

Как есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что не так? `required` проверяет на `length > 0`, а `email` - там под капотом есть регулярка

Comment: Высвечивает сразу и required, и email

Comment: а как должно? изначально `value` в инпуте равняется `null`, это значение не проходит ни ту, ни ту проверку

Comment: если использую pattern, то сначала required, а потом pattern

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation здесь даже есть пример

Comment: там в Email по очереди показывает ошибки

Comment: что значит по очереди?

Comment: хотя должно высветиться: "Email не может быть пустым. Введите корректный email."

а когда появится хотя бы 1 символ: "Введите корректный email."

Comment: посмотри на сайте что я скинул. Там не появляется сразу что требуется email и email неверный
PS изменил ссылку

Comment: потому что там условие `submitted` еще есть :)

Comment: после submitted пиши в поле, и как видишь там не появляется сразу 2 ошибки

Comment: можешь submitted удалить и все равно работает как нужно

Comment: хорошо, в чем у тебя проблема?

Comment: добавил картинки

Answer (score -1):

Проблема оказалась в 5-ой версии Angular'a. В Angular 6 все работает как надо